# Best practice using ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecs

What would be the best practice in terms of high security and functionality of using ALB with the Docker containers that are inside private subnets? Should I install ALB in public subnet with the internet or installing ALB in private subnet would be the best thing to do in order to secure instances inside private subnet while using ALB features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of public or private for a load balancer entirely depends on how you want to access the load balancer. If traffic will be hitting the load balancer from the Internet then the load balancer has to exist in a public subnet. If traffic will only be originating from within your VPC, then the load balancer can be in a private subnet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. If I want to configure ALB in public subnet with internet access (HTTPS only) and Docker containers inside private subnet with NAT and AWS ECS, do I need to enable HTTP (port 80) in ALB or Target group?

Comment: Since SSL is terminated at the load balancer you would need HTTP enabled in the target group unless you are also installing SSL certificates in your web servers.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response. I have installed a SSL certificate in ALB (public subnet) and configured Target Group with HTTPS enabled. Isn't that enough to pass HTTPS traffic to AWS ECS Docker containers inside private subnet? I am having unhealthy or draining health status on HTTPS Target Group. When I tested without HTTPS but only with HTTP Target Group, HTTP Target Group status is healthy. Did I miss anything when I configured HTTPS on ALB or with AWS ECS Task Definitions?

Comment: HTTPS will stop at the load balancer, because that's where the SSL certificate is installed. The communication between the load balancer and your docker containers will need to be HTTP.

Comment: It means there is no purpose of using SSL Certificate in ALB if communication between ALB and Docker containers in private subnet is not secure. What would be the best practice of implementing ALB and AWS ECS with Docker containers in order to have secure communication?

Comment: Communication between ALB and your ECS containers is contained entirely within your VPC so why do you care if it is encrypted? It's secure within your VPC, just not encrypted. If you really care, then install SSL certificates on your ECS containers.

Comment: Thank you so much for making things crystal clear. I will go ahead and keep my configuration as it is. Thanks again and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to **Mark B** answer I would say that the best security practice for ALB is to use an HTTPS protocol with a valid certificate on any schemes: *public* and  *private*!

For most cases, you may pass traffic to a Target Group with HTTP port, this is one of the reasons for using ALB. But in a higly secure environment, you should pass traffic to HTTPS too.